# Unity .3ds file is purple

Tags: unity

I imported a .3ds file from skethup and in the preview it shows it with the texture, but when I put it in the scene it shows it without the texture.

http://puu.sh/gyYSU/a09541420c.png

Comment: have you tried exporting SketchUp model as .fbx?

Comment: @2600th It works, but now if I look at it from other angles it disapears.. And it does not show the full texture example: http://puu.sh/gz0LF/d960127756.jpg looks like http://puu.sh/gz0QR/1674891653.png

Answer (score 0):

Export the SketchUp model as .fbx and select "[Export two-sided faces](http://help.sketchup.com/en/article/114381)" in the menu.

Comment: Is there a way to fix my texturing issue?

Comment: You can view more info here : http://bim.wikispaces.com/SketchUp+to+Unity+Workflow+Steps